# Change a redis password without external downtime

Tags: security, passwords, redis

I would like to refresh redis server password. The issue is that there are some external services using it so until I propagate this change thing will eventually stop working.

From my research I have only seen the `requirepass` command + the server restart, but this has downtime.

With other databases like Postgres, I would create new user-password, migrate permissions, change at application level and then invalidate the previous access.

How can I do this process in redis?

Comment: Have u gone through [this](https://redis.io/topics/acl).By using this you can create multiple users and set permissions for them

Answer (score 6):

You can change the password without downtime by issuing:

```
redis> CONFIG SET requirepass <your new password>
```

To persist the changes for next restart, edit your .conf file or issue a `CONFIG REWRITE`.